# Line numbers/ line height for a Qml TextArea

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, kde-plasma

We want to implement an embedded code editor in our QtQuick based application. For highlighting we use a `QSyntaxHighlighter` based on `KSyntaxHighlighting`. We found no way to determine the line height and line spacing that would allow us to display line numbers next to the code. Supporting dynamic line-wrap would also be a great addition.

```
    Flickable {
            id: flickable
            flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
            Layout.maximumWidth: parent.width
            Layout.minimumHeight: 200
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
            clip: true
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
                width: 15
                active: true
                policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            }

            property int rowHeight: textArea.font.pixelSize+3
            property int marginsTop: 10
            property int marginsLeft: 4
            property int lineCountWidth: 40

            Column {
                id: lineNumbers
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: flickable.marginsLeft
                anchors.topMargin:   flickable.marginsTop
                y:  flickable.marginsTop
                width: flickable.lineCountWidth

                function range(start, end) {
                    var rangeArray = new Array(end-start);
                    for(var i = 0; i < rangeArray.length; i++){
                        rangeArray[i] = start+i;
                    }
                    return rangeArray;
                }

                Repeater {
                    model: textArea.lineCount
                    delegate:
                    Label {
                        color: (!visualization.urdfPreviewIsOK && (index+1) === visualization.urdfPreviewErrorLine) ? "white" :  "#666"
                        font: textArea.font
                        width: parent.width
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                        height: flickable.rowHeight
                        renderType: Text.NativeRendering
                        text: index+1
                        background: Rectangle {
                            color: (!visualization.urdfPreviewIsOK && (index+1) === visualization.urdfPreviewErrorLine) ? "red" : "white"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Rectangle {
                y: 4
                height: parent.height
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: flickable.lineCountWidth + flickable.marginsLeft
                width: 1
                color: "#ddd"
            }

        TextArea.flickable: TextArea {
                id: textArea

                property bool differentFromSavedState: fileManager.textDifferentFromSaved

                text: fileManager.textTmpState
                textFormat: Qt.PlainText
                //dont wrap to allow for easy line annotation wrapMode: TextArea.Wrap
                focus: false
                selectByMouse: true
                leftPadding: flickable.marginsLeft+flickable.lineCountWidth
                rightPadding: flickable.marginsLeft
                topPadding: flickable.marginsTop
                bottomPadding: flickable.marginsTop

                background: Rectangle {
                    color: "white"
                    border.color: "green"
                    border.width: 1.5
                }

                Component.onCompleted: {
                    fileManager.textEdit = textArea.textDocument
                }

                onTextChanged: {
                    fileManager.textTmpState = text
                }

                function update()
                {
                    text = fileManager.textTmpState
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see we use `property int rowHeight: textArea.font.pixelSize+3` to guess the line height and line spacing but that of course breaks as soon as DPI or other properties of the system change.

Comment: Take a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontmetrics.html. You can also get access to the text document to do more advanced stuff: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#textDocument-prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextArea` type has two properties `contentWidth` and `contentHeight` which contains the size of the text content.

So, if you divide the height by the number of lines (which you can get with the property `lineCount`), you will get the height of a line:

```
property int rowHeight: textArea.contentHeight / textArea.lineCount
```

But, if you plan to have multiple line spacing in the same document, you will have to handle each line by manipulating the `QTextDocument`:

```
class LineManager: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int lineCount READ lineCount NOTIFY lineCountChanged)
public:
    LineManager(): QObject(), document(nullptr)
    {}
    Q_INVOKABLE void setDocument(QQuickTextDocument* qdoc)
    {
        document = qdoc->textDocument();
        connect(document, &QTextDocument::blockCountChanged, this, &LineManager::lineCountChanged);
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE int lineCount() const
    {
        if (!document)
            return 0;
        return document->blockCount();
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE int height(int lineNumber) const
    {
        return int(document->documentLayout()->blockBoundingRect(document->findBlockByNumber(lineNumber)).height());
    }
signals:
    void lineCountChanged();
private:
    QTextDocument* document;
};
```

```
    LineManager* mgr = new LineManager();
    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
    view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("lineCounter", mgr);
    view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view->show();
```

```
Repeater {
    model: lineCounter.lineCount
    delegate:
        Label {
            color: "#666"
            font: textArea.font
            width: parent.width
            height: lineCounter.height(index)
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            renderType: Text.NativeRendering
            text: index+1
            background: Rectangle {
                border.color: "black"
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how I would detect (if enabled) dynamic word wrap? I assume it's somewhere in `QTextDocument` but when I had a look there I found nothing usefull (ie height was always 0 etc)

Comment: Do you want to know if the word wrap is enabled or if the text has been modified to be wrapped?

Comment: well when I have wordwrap enabled those lines with actual wordwrap should have only one line number right? So somehow I need to loop over something and check for each line if it is a complete one or a continued/wrapped one?

Comment: You can get the height of each line by manipulating the `QTextDocument`. I'll update my answer with a C++ version to handle that. I'll try to reproduce it in QML, also.

Answer (score 0):

I found a QML only solution:

1. Use `TextEdit` instead of `TextArea` to avoid alignment issues between line numbers and text
2. Use a 'ListView' to generate the line numbers for the text edit:

Here is an initial solution:

```
    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ListView {
            Layout.preferredWidth: 30
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            model: textEdit.text.split(/\n/g)
            delegate: Text { text: index + 1 }
        }
        TextEdit {
            id: textEdit
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
    }
```

The `ListView` has a complete copy of each row of text. We can use this copy to compute the line height (taking into account of word wrap). We do this by creating an invisible `Text`. We can improve the answer further by adding a `Flickable` to the `TextEdit` and synchronize the scroll between the `ListView` and the `TextEdit`:

Here is a more complete solution:

```
// NumberedTextEdit.qml

import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Item {
    property alias lineNumberFont: lineNumbers.textMetrics.font
    property color lineNumberBackground: "#e0e0e0"
    property color lineNumberColor: "black"
    property alias font: textEdit.font
    property alias text: textEdit.text
    property color textBackground: "white"
    property color textColor: "black"

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent

        color: textBackground

        ListView {
            id: lineNumbers
            property TextMetrics textMetrics: TextMetrics { text: "99999"; font: textEdit.font }
            model: textEdit.text.split(/\n/g)
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.margins: 10
            width: textMetrics.boundingRect.width
            clip: true

            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: lineNumbers.width
                height: lineText.height
                color: lineNumberBackground
                Text {
                    id: lineNumber
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    text: index + 1
                    color: lineNumberColor
                    font: textMetrics.font
                }

                Text {
                    id: lineText
                    width: flickable.width
                    text: modelData
                    font: textEdit.font
                    visible: false
                    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                }
            }
            onContentYChanged: {
                if (!moving) return
                flickable.contentY = contentY
            }
        }

        Item {
            anchors.left: lineNumbers.right
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.margins: 10

            Flickable {
                id: flickable
                anchors.fill: parent
                clip: true
                contentWidth: textEdit.width
                contentHeight: textEdit.height
                TextEdit {
                    id: textEdit
                    width: flickable.width
                    color: textColor
                    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                }
                onContentYChanged: {
                    if (lineNumbers.moving) return
                    lineNumbers.contentY = contentY
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that you can query the line height using `FontMetrics` and then getting the true height by `Math.ceil(fontMetrics.lineSpacing)` for example:

```
TextEdit {
    id: textArea

     FontMetrics {
         id: fontMetricsId
         font: textArea.font
     }

     Component.onCompleted: {
          console.log("Line spacing:" + Math.ceil(fontMetricsId.lineSpacing)
     }
}
```